# Replace column values with certain row values for multiple files using awk/sed

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I want to:

- Replace column values with certain row values using `awk` or `sed`
- Do this for multiple csv files in a loop as explained below.

File1.csv:

```
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
```

File2.csv:

```
XYZ, 123
QWE, 456
```

Want to replace:

- 2nd column in File 1 with [1st column OF 1st row] value in File 2
- and 3rd column in File 1 with [2nd column OF 1st row] value in File 2

To get output as below:

```
A,XYZ,123,D
E,XYZ,123,D
```

Have to do this for multiple files in the sense, the 2nd file which was looking as below:

```
R,W,O,P
S,D,I,L
```

Would change as below...

```
R,QWE,456,P
S,QWE,456,L
```

Let me know how to do this using `awk` and in a loop

1. I tried as below but its not working (in `awk`):

   ```
   awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' file2.csv file1.csv
   ```
2. Also I tried running this `awk` in a loop over a directory of files:

   ```
   for file in transmaster*.csv
   do
     echo $file
     awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' file2.csv file1.csv

   done
   ```

... but get below error :

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `file' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Always try to select an answer after sometime of your post and when enough answers are there as correct one to close the thread completely too.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR,1]=$1
  a[FNR,2]=$2
  next
}
{
  $2=a[FNR,1]
  $3=a[FNR,2]
}
1' FS=", " file2.csv  FS="," OFS="," file1.csv
```

Comment: Ravinder, thanks for the reply. Its working but only partly.


As mentioned above, I have bunch of CSV files and for each file, I want to replace 


- 2nd column in File 1 with [1st column OF 1st row] value in File 2 
- and 3rd column in File 1 with [2nd column OF 1st row] value in File 2 


So for 1st CSV, I use Row 1 values from File 2
For 2nd CSV, I use Row 2 values from File 2
... and so on.